# How to test a method inside an implementation in Rust

Tags: testing, methods, rust

I'm trying to increase the test coverage in my Rust application.  I have read lots about testing public functions and testing private functions and adding the "tests" directory in order to add integration tests.  But I have not read anything about testing of methods within an implementation.  I've tried googling a bit for this but I'm not finding anything.

Here is a simple example, is this how I am meant to implement the testing?

```
struct Rectangle {
    width: usize,
    length: usize,
}

impl Rectangle {
    pub fn new(width: usize, length: usize) -> Rectangle {
        Rectangle {
            width,
            length,
        }
    }

    fn area(&mut self) -> usize {
        self.width * self.length
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_rectangle() {
        let mut rectangle = Rectangle::new(4, 5);
        
        assert_eq!(20, rectangle.area())
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK yes. What you did seems to be a common and nice way. One more thing you could is write doc tests on your method. That would be a little more organised as a small test would be at the same place as the method.

Comment: Incase if you missed: [unit tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#unit-tests), [testing-private-functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#testing-private-functions)

Comment: A method **is** a function.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is exactly how you are meant to test struct methods. The Rust book has a chapter called [Test Organization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html) which states:

> The purpose of unit tests is to test each unit of code in isolation from the rest of the code to quickly pinpoint where code is and isn’t working as expected. You’ll put unit tests in the *src* directory in each file with the code that they’re testing. The convention is to create a module named `tests` in each file to contain the test functions and to annotate the module with `cfg(test)`.

Another common test organization methods is using [documentation tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html). `rustdoc` supports executing your documentation examples as tests. So running `cargo test` on the example below would cause the `area` function to execute as a test:

````rust
impl Rectangle {
    /// ```rust
    /// use crate::Rectangle;
    ///
    /// let mut rectangle = Rectangle::new(4, 5);
    /// assert_eq!(20, rectangle.area())
    /// ```
    fn area(&mut self) -> usize {
        self.width * self.length
    }
}
````

Comment: Thanks @Ibraheem.  Is it at all common to move all the unit tests for a module into their own file?  Currently I have all of the tests at the bottom of the file.

Comment: @Nocker It really is a matter of preference. For example, [warp](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp) keeps most of its unit tests in a `/tests` directory. actix-web on the other hand has [1500 line files where half of it is just tests](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/master/src/scope.rs). The convention is definitely to create a module named tests in the same file as the code being tested, and the `tests` directory is meant for unit tests. But if you like it better seperated, go for it!